# Program using SQLite running only from bin\Debug location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I wrote a program that uses SQLite database, I added the required references and the program runs smoothly.

After I copy the .exe, the two directories with the SQLite dlls (x86 and x64) and System.Data.SQLite.dll and xml and the database file to a custom location, the program won't start.

I clicked on it and nothing happens like I haven't clicked on it. No error messages.

But when I click on the .exe in the bin\Debug directory, the program starts as it should.

What causes this problem?

EDIT:

I was able to attach the debugger and found that three processes are running with the same name as this project and wntdll.pdb is not loaded and ntdll.dll was not found.

Comment: add some form of tracing you can check without running within VS: some messagebox, or write message on some log file. it really depends on your code, put a trace after each "important" instructions an most important in every exception you catch. Consider writing your main as `try{...} catch(Excepton e){ TraceSomeOw(ex.ToString()}`

Comment: The application doesn't start, so I can't check messageboxes or exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know about your code, it's a bit hard to give specific answer, but generally running an application dependent on external reference would depend on how it is addressed.
From [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rORUm.png), make sure your DLLs' "Copy Local" is set to true. This will add a copy of your SQLite reference next to executable.

Answer (score 0):

you actually don't know if your program "doesn't start", not entering the main at all, or exit from `Main` as soon after enter it.
Try to put a

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

as a first line of the main: you will be able to attach VS debugger in this way (the PC is the same where you have VS, ain't it?).

If you copy in the same folder also the .pdb files, debugger will be able to load the source code.

Comment: I was able to attach the debugger this way. Three processes is running with the same name as the project. Is this normal or it should be only one process?

wntdll.pdb not loaded and ntdll.dll was not found

Comment: so  your program "start", now keep going and find what is wrong. Having 3 process with same project name sound strange, they can be the same exe launched before that seemed "not started". I  would kill all of them and launch again the program.

Comment: I can't kill all of the processes. I'm trying like this: "taskkill /im "project.exe" /f".

The result: two is killed, but one remains and I got this error message: Proccess with xxxx PID cannot be terminated. REASON: there is no running instance of the task."

But I see it in the tasklist